# Search in an array of hashes by the hash key and its sorting in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array of hashes of about 300 hash items:

```
@whole = [
          {
            'id' => 112,
            'name' => 'Wheelbase',
            'lang' => 'en'
          },
          {
            'lang' => 'en',
            'name' => 'Width',
            'id' => 57
          },
          {
            'lang' => 'en',
            'id' => 174,
            'name' => 'WLAN'
          },
          {
            'id' => 252,
            'name' => 'Zoom System',
            'lang' => 'en'
          };
];
```

I want to search multiple key names in above data structure with multiple names stored in another array.

```
@props = ('Price', 'Market Dominance', 'Market Capitalization');
```

And my code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@matching_items, @whole);  # input arrays both
my $id_prop;

@matching_items = grep {
  foreach my $in (@props) {
    if ($_->{name} =~ /^$in$/i) {
        $id_prop = $_->{id};
        print "$id_prop\n";
    }
  }
  } @whole;

print Dumper @matching_items;
```

which is not populating the matched items in @matching_items. It is returning as empty and printing only id to console. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `grep` code block needs to evaluate to a true value to accept that list element.

Comment: so how can i modify my code to reflect true value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
my @whole = (
    {
        'id' => 112,
        'name' => 'Wheelbase',
        'lang' => 'en'
    },
    {
        'lang' => 'en',
        'name' => 'Width',
        'id' => 57
    },
);

my %props = map {$_ => 1} ('Width', 'Market Dominance', 'Market Capitalization');
my @matching_items = grep { exists $props{$_->{name}} } @whole;
```

Comment: Your code is short and near to one-liner. Can you explain what it is doing (the last two lines)?

Comment: Its creating a hash, and then searching the big array for input name which exists in hash and the matching ones are sent to matched array. wow thanks.

Comment: Ok I accept this solution. I have a little modification if you can do. Can this code be modified to generate a notification/print to console that specific items/keys in inputted small hash (%props) were not found in addition to matching?

Comment: The matching ones will go to @matching_items while the unmatched will be printed.

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://pastebin.com/rf4szmgF) ?

Comment: The website Pastebin is not opening on my laptop and mobile browser.

Comment: Strange that it does not work.. Can you try [this](https://gist.github.com/hakonhagland/66d3c9d19b103f7cfabaf0f9583b6ffd) instead.

Comment: I got it. No, because it involves another operation. Besides I don't want another array. Also, its not fulfilling my second requirement. I just need to evaluate only input %props elements against @whole. Whether any element in %props is included or not. Instead of grep, can we use another map operation or a combined map and grep operation?

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://gist.github.com/hakonhagland/66d3c9d19b103f7cfabaf0f9583b6ffd) then?

Comment: No, its returning all the items of @whole that are not in %props.

Comment: Whereas I just need those items of %props that are not in @whole.

Comment: Ok, let me try again.. What about [this](https://gist.github.com/hakonhagland/66d3c9d19b103f7cfabaf0f9583b6ffd) ?

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a reference literal to `@whole`, I changed this to an array. The nested `foreach`can easier be written using `List::Util::any` which will shortcut on the first element that makes the block evaluate to true. I also lowercased your `@props` entries once before looping and used `eq` to compare to the lowercased name strings:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/any/;
use Data::Dumper;
use 5.016;

my @whole = (
          {
            'id' => 112,
            'name' => 'Wheelbase',
            'lang' => 'en'
          },
          {
            'lang' => 'en',
            'name' => 'Width',
            'id' => 57
          },
          {
            'lang' => 'en',
            'id' => 174,
            'name' => 'WLAN'
          },
          {
            'id' => 252,
            'name' => 'Zoom System',
            'lang' => 'en'
          }
);

my @props = ('Price', 'Market Dominance', 'Market Capitalization','Zoom System');

my @props_lc = map {lc} @props;

my @matching_items = grep {
    my $name = lc $_->{name};
    any {$name eq $_} @props_lc;
} @whole;

print Dumper @matching_items;
```

Comment: Does library List::Util comes in default installation of Perl? I don't want to install any libraries for such a small task, specially in Perl due to its powerful parsing data capabilities.

Comment: List::Util is in core.